# Can't use auto-generated protobuf classes when Access is Internal

Tags: c#, .net, grpc

I have a protobuf file, and I added it to my project in `.csproj` with:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Protobuf Include="Grpc/Protos/my.proto" GrpcServices="Client" Access="Internal" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

My project is supposed to be a nuget package that exposes a client for accessing some grpc service (defined by `my.proto`). I do not want to expose publicly the auto-generated grpc client. Instead, I want to wrap it in my own class where I do some boilerplate things to simplify code of the clients of my grpc service.

With that in mind, I set `Access="Internal"` for my protobuf. It did auto-generate classes for my service and messages and placed them in `obj/Debug/net6.0/Grpc/Protos/`. The classes are `internal`, just like I wanted, so theoretically I should be able to access the classes only within my project. But... I can't.

The imports that used to work when I had `Access="Public"` stopped working. My proto file has a `Search` service, and normally I would reference it like this:

```cs
MyProject.Grpc.Protos.Search.SearchClient _client;
```

(the namespace in my proto file is `MyProject.Grpc.Protos`

Now, this line produces an error:

> Cannot resolve symbol 'Protos'

Why is that? Is my understanding wrong? I assumed that auto-generated internal classes within my project should be available within that project.

Comment: The [protobuf compiler docu](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp-generated) says that the *internal* flag for the compiler the generated types have an *internal* instead of a *public* access modifier. So it should work like you said. I would open the generated C# code in the file system (it should be in some folder in your project) and look at the generated namespaces and access modifiers, then it should be clear why you cannot access it from your project.

Comment: Yeah, I did verify that. It generated `internal` classes within my project's `obj/Debug/net6.0/Grpc/Protos/` directory. If I understand `internal` correctly, I should be able to access these classes within that project - but I can't!

Comment: Hm weird, I would expect the same behaviour